# How do you bind an icon image to a DataGridView using value of 0 and 1 to denote online and offline?

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview, icons

I have a database table with columns username, password and status (being 0 and 1 for offline and online respectively).

I am trying to bind an icon image to the datagrid column, based on the value on the value of status from the database.

I keep getting a "Object reference not set to instance of an object" exception thrown when trying this.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds = ce.getData("select username, statusOfUser from users;");

            var coluser = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "username", DataPropertyName = "username", HeaderText = "Username"};

            var colstatus = new DataGridViewImageColumn() { Name = "statusOfUser", DataPropertyName = "statusOfUser", HeaderText = "Status", ValuesAreIcons = false };

            //var colStatusId = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "statusOfUser", DataPropertyName = "statusOfUser", HeaderText = "statusOfUser" };
            dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(coluser, colstatus/*, colStatusId*/);

            Image[] status_images = { Image.FromFile("../../../../Icons/offline.ico"), Image.FromFile("../../../../Icons/online.ico") };

            for (int k = 0; k <= ds.Tables["users"].Rows.Count - 1; k++)
            {
                var row_data = ds.Tables["users"].Rows[k];
                int status_id = (int)row_data["statusOfUser"];
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row_data["username"], status_images[status_id], row_data["statusOfUser"]);
                dataGridView1.Rows[k].Height = 22;
            }

            //scroll to end
            if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0) { dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; } //scroll datagridview to last row / end
```

I have tried an if statement at each record to add the icons but found this very cumbersome and added a lot of unnecessary overhead.

> p.s. Database tables have values in them

Comment: in which line you get this error?

Comment: @Damith I checked.. its around :  for (int k = 0; k <= ds.Tables["users"].Rows.Count - 1; k++)

Comment: put break point on that line and run again, use quick watch and find which object is null

Comment: @Damith the error i keep getting is about casting int status_id = (int)row_data["statusOfUser"];

Comment: there may be null values for statusOfUser